# How to quickly batch build only 64-bit in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

My Visual Studio solution consists of about 50 projects (and growing). Each project has three configurations (*Debug*, *Release*, and *CodeAnalysis*) and two platforms (Win32 and x64). That's a total of ~300 build combinations.

I regularly need to swap between building all ~300 combinations and building only the 64-bit configurations (which is ~150 entries).

I know that I can manually select the 64-bit configurations in the Batch Build window, but it seems I still need to check each box individually. 150 clicks are time-consuming and annoying once, let alone periodically.

I know that I can select x64 along with a single configuration from the *Standard* toolbar, but that gives me only a single configuration which means I'd have to wait/monitor the build, select the second configuration, and finally the third. Much fewer clicks, but I'd rather not have to babysit the build.

So, is there a quick/easy way to select all & only the 64-bit configurations to do a batch build (or something equivalent)?

(If it matters, I'm using Visual Studio 2017.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the commandline "msbuild" command without parameters. By default, it will build using solution/project files.

You can have two scripts, one which lists the solutions/projects, and one which specifies just 64 bit.

For example:

```
cd MyProjects\
msbuild.exe
```

and then

```
cd MyProjects\
msbuild.exe /p:Platform=x64
```

Comment: Thanks for the command-line suggestion.  I'll give it a try.  While I have no problem using the command line (most of my days are spent developing on Linux), I'm curious if there's a way to accomplish this through the VS GUI.

Comment: You could setup custom solution configurations (e.g. Only 64-bit), select the projects to build and the target platform (x64) in Visual Studio.

Comment: To save the clicks, you can open the solution file as XML and do a mass replace.